# How to insert a set of entries into mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, methods, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to operate mongodb. Now I want to save a set of entries (array of objects) to a collcetion.

I have found the below given example but I think I can save only one object by using save().

```
var arvind = new User({
name : 'Arvind',
age : 99,
DOB : '01/01/1915',
isAlive : true
});

arvind.save(function (err, data) {
if (err) console.log(err);
else console.log('Saved : ', data );
});
```

Which method should I use to save set of entries to collection?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var UserArray = [{ "name" : "Users1"},{ "name" : "Users2"}];

Users.collection.insert(UserArray,  function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        // TODO: handle error
    } else {
        console.info('%d potatoes were successfully stored.', docs.length);
    }
});
```